# How to find a specific value in object object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

basically my questions is how could I able to get specific value for example I will provide below
I got an object

```
const roomList = { 
    1234: { id:1234, name: "room1" },
    5678: { id:5678, name: "sectionA" }
   }
```

Base on this situation am I able to get the object of `{ id:1234, name: "room1" }` without loop through the roomList. When I only have room1 detail. Could I get the object when I have an input of room1 how could I get the `{ id:1234, name: "room1"}` object? I try loop but that is not the way I want could I know any possible to directly point to the object with this value(room1) without loop through the object??

Answer (score 3):

```js
const roomList ={
   1234: { id:1234, name: "room1" },
   5678: { id:5678, name: "sectionA" }
};
const roomNameToFind = "room1";
const roomFound = Object.values(roomList).find(room => room.name === roomNameToFind);
console.log(roomFound)
```

You just need to look at the values of your object and find your room amongst your objects.

I guess this is what you are expecting.